# Using Zend_Service_Twitter to fetch last tweets from a user without using OAuth?

Tags: zend-framework, twitter

As far as I know Twitter API is supposed to be available with smaller limit rate without API key and without being connected through OAuth.

Is there anyway to use that simply through Zend_Service_Twitter ? Or will I end parsing some kind of feed like that : https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/12345.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979933/zend-framework-how-to-get-my-statuses-from-twitter) same answer :

```
    $twitter_search = new Zend_Service_Twitter_Search('json');
    $response = $twitter_search->search('from:twitter_handle');
    print_r($response);die;
```